# Calling a void method from a static main method

Tags: java, method-call

I'm trying to call a void method from my static main method. Here's what I have:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    Scene scene = new Scene();
    Animate animate = new animate();
    animate();    //I've tried it by itself, but no luck
}
public void animate(){
    sun.slowMoveHorizontal(5000);
    moon.slowHorizontal(400);
}
```

If anyone could help it would be much appreciated. The text says, "Add a call to animate in your main method just below the line that creates the Scene object." If that helps.

Comment: Delete `Animate animate = new animate();`.

Comment: I still get "cannot reference a non static element from a static context"

Comment: You are trying to call the method *from inside* your main method. Not 'to'.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming `Animate` is a proper class, you need to call the instance method on an actual instance.

For example.

```
Animate a = new Animate();
a.animate();
```

Otherwise, check out the Scene class. Are you supposed to animate that?

Comment: I apologize, but when I do that "Animate" and "Animate()" cannot be found as symbols.

Comment: @Dearerburrito That would also have been a problem with the code you posted. You didn't mention it in your question.

Comment: @Dear We cannot guess at your code without a [mcve]

Comment: Thank you, so I'm not just calling the method improperly, it's something else.

Comment: @Dearerburrito You need to instantiate the current class, whatever it is. This answer assumes it is `Animate`, based on what you posted. It is up to you to clarify your question.

Comment: @Dear based on `Animate animate` in the question, I assume that class exists. Otherwise, the code provided isn't compiling for multiple reasons . But you've not shown your class definition(s) in full, so please edit the question to include more code

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
public void animate(){
```

To:

```
public static void animate(){
```

You are trying to invoke a non-static method from a static one.

---

If `animate()` is an instance member, you instantiate the object and call `animate()` from that object:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    Animation a = new Animation();
    a.animate();
}
```

Comment: Now my variables "sun" and "moon" are out of context cause they're not static

Comment: If animate() is part of a class, you instantiate the object and call animate() from that object. If animate() is just a method which exist alongside with your main(), set it as static.

Comment: When I instantiate it, I still get "cannot find symbol - class Animate"

Comment: @Dearerburrito You have to post more code (at least enough to show where you declared the variables and methods). We all know what is the problem, but it's hard to explain to you when you show minimal codes.

Comment: `animate()` *is* part of a class. Everything in Java is part of a class.

Comment: @EJP I know that line is flawed, but OP should know what I mean. I've edited it anyway.

Comment: Your edit is no improvement. The term 'instance member' springs to mind. And there isnn Thug wrong with invoking a non-static method from a static method, as your own later example shows.

Comment: @EJP Right, I just couldn't think of a good term. Have edited it..haha